# C# push notification working on emulator but not on real device

Tags: c#, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send notification when data enter in `db` using c#. I have done something but i don't know what I did wrong in my code, the problem is

> when I run on emulator push notification working fine but when I run
>   on real device I didn't get push notification.

please help me out.
thanks in advance.

here is my **`manifest`** ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.studentcares.spps">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver android:name="com.studentcares.spps.otpReader.SmsReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service           
   android:name="com.studentcares.spps.firebase.MyFirebaseMesagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name="com.studentcares.spps.firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>  
    <activity android:name="com.studentcares.spps.dialogBox.NotifyNetworkConnectionMessage"/>
    <activity android:name="com.studentcares.spps.MainActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="com.studentcares.spps.SplashScreen"/>        
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.apps.photos.permission.GOOGLE_PHOTOS"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
</manifest>
```

here is **`firebaseMessaging`** Service Code,

```
public class MyFirebaseMesagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    showNotification(remoteMessage);
    //showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
}
private void showNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    //intent.putExtra("Message", remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("FCM Notification");
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_short);
    notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    notificationBuilder.setPriority(2);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent) ;
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());
}
}
```

here is my c# code,

```
try
    {

        string applicationID = "server api key";

        string senderId = "sender id";

        string deviceId = "registration fcm id";

        WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
        tRequest.Method = "post";
        tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        var data = new
        {
            to = deviceId,
            notification = new
            {
                body = "test",
                title = "Push Notification",
                sound = "Enabled"

            }
        };
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = serializer.Serialize(data);
        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                    {
                        String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                        string str = sResponseFromServer;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you positive that you're using the corresponding registration token for the device? Are you receiving an error response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever getting this issue then just restart your device it will working well.